# Why this callback doesn't gets called unless I assign the result of this function to a class variable

Tags: ios, swift

I have this function that is from the AppAuth examples, I realised that in iOS13 I don't really need to store the return value for the OIDAuthState.authState, so I tried to clean up the code by removing the `appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow =`, but once I remove that, the callback doesn't gets called anymore. And this currentAuthorizationFlow is not used anywhere else in the code.

I have also tried assigning the result of `OIDAuthState.authState` to a function local variable, where the call back also will not be called.

If I assign the results of `OIDAuthState.authState` to a class member variable in the current class, then the call back will be called.

Why is the behaviour as such? It seems very baffling to me.

```
func signInGmail() {
    let redirectURI = URL(string: gmail_kRedirectURI)!
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
    let config = GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization.configurationForGoogle()
    let scopes = [OIDScopeOpenID, OIDScopeProfile, OIDScopeEmail, kGTLRAuthScopeGmailReadonly]
    
    let request = OIDAuthorizationRequest.init(configuration: config, clientId: gmail_kClientID, scopes: scopes, redirectURL: redirectURI, responseType: OIDResponseTypeCode, additionalParameters: nil)
    
    appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: self, callback: { (authState, error) in
        //handleError
        
        if let authState = authState {
            let authorizer = GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization(authState: authState)
            
            self.pickGmailLabels(authorizer: authorizer)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Does this [github issue comment](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/197#issuecomment-375806729) help you?

Comment: @EricHua no, my URL are ok, as the difference is just me removing that assignment for the result of OIDAuthState.authState call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the [documentation](https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/docs/latest/interface_o_i_d_auth_state.html#ae32fd0732cd3192cd5219f2655a4c85c) says about the return value of `authState(byPresenting:presenting:callback:)`

> Returns
> A OIDExternalUserAgentSession instance which will terminate when it receives a cancel (OIDExternalUserAgentSession-p) message, or after processing a resumeExternalUserAgentFlowWithURL: (OIDExternalUserAgentSession-p) message.

What might happen here is that either the dealloc for the returned session calls `cancel`, or the session along with the callback get deallocated if no one retains them. And since you no longer store a reference to it when you remove the assignment, the session might get discarded right away.
However the need to retain the session is not explicitly stated into the documentation, so if this is the root cause of the problem, either the documentation is laking this piece of information, or there's a bug in the implementation.

Note that it's not an unusual pattern having to hold on some async task identifier to make sure the whole operation completes, however this should be stated into the documentation, if this is the intended behaviour.

Comment: I try to confirm such theory "What likely happens is either the dealloc for the returned session calls cancel", by searching implementation of protocol `OIDExternalUserAgentSession`. But, I fail to locate implementation. Are you able to find such? Thanks.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng I also did a quick search through the library's codebase, and didn't found anything relevant. Changed the wording in my answer from "likely" to "maybe" :) There is other answerer on this question, maybe they could help you with this query.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at the right direction, there's no dealloc in that class, but they did a lot of weak references which seems to be causing the issue. I have filed a issue at https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/600

Answer (score 0):

The function returns an object, and you need to keep that object alive. That is done by assigning it to a strong variable. If you don't do that, then the object will be released at the next opportunity.

Comment: I also "blamed this", however this is not explicitly stated into the documentation, so if this is the root cause of the problem, either the documentation is laking this piece of information, or there's a bug in the implementation,

Comment: But, how does the returned object deallocation, relate to callback is not being called, exactly?